# Including CDATA wrapper while Marshalling

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-serialization, xmlbeans

I am generating xml using XMLBeans .
Is there a way to include CDATA Wrapper automatically for required elements in the output xml document .
For example , my output xml should look like this :

```
<employee>
<name><![CDATA[NAME]]></name>
<address><![CDATA[ADDRESS]]></address>
</employee>
```

1) Can we write XSD in such a way , that whenever i set value for `<name>` element in my program using XMLBeans , the output xml should contain name element like this : `<name><![CDATA[NAME]]></name>` instead of `<name>NAME</name>`

2) Is there a way in XMLBeans to produce CDATA Wrapper for specific elements .

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't mean to be a wiseguy, but curious: why do you need this?

Comment: <name> element could have a value which itself a large xml and in that case the value is expected to be wrapped by CDATA

Answer (score 2):

See [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/CDATA-Example-td17259867.html).  In short:

```
node.setFoo("ABCDE12345"); 
XmlCursor c = node.xgetFoo().newCursor(); 
c.toFirstContentToken(); 
c.setBookmark(CDataBookmark.CDATA_BOOKMARK);
```

And then when you go to "save" the document be sure to pass in an XmlOptions like:

```
XmlOptions opts = new XmlOptions().setUseCDataBookmarks(); 
node.xmlText(opts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reading docs - I'm not an XMLBeans user.  If someone with experience writes differently - trust them, not me.

See [CDataBookmark](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/CDataBookmark.html) and [XmlOptions](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.html#setSaveCDataEntityCountThreshold%28int%29).setCDATAEntityCountThreshold,setUseCDataBookmarks,setSaveCDataLengthThreshold.

The docs on how you set a CDataBookmark in the text aren't clear.  See [this bit from Nabble](http://old.nabble.com/CDATA-Bookmark-problem,-xmlbeans-version-2.4-td21448916.html).

Comment: Well i am not sure if there is a way through XMLBeans.Still trying.
By th way , Is it possible through XSD ,one which i have mentioned in option 1) .

Thanks

Comment: So, you inserted bookmarks, turned on the options, and it didn't work?  And no, there's nothing in an XSD that will do this.  By the way... if you don't use CDATA, you should be getting character entities in your output instead for "<" and "&" (e.g., &amp; for ampersand).  If you aren't, something is really wrong in the way you're outputting stuff.